# How can I calculate the required points of a 'stroked' triangle, from its original vectors

Tags: trigonometry

I have a triangle defined as three sets of x/y coordinates or `vectors`:

```
v0 = (0, 1)
v1 = (1, 1)
v2 = (0.7, 0)
```

When drawn the triangle produces the `yellow` triangle as shown in the image below:

[image]

I need to be able to calculate the coordinates of the outer `black` triangle and the inner `blue` rectangle, depending on a single `strokeWidth` variable.

Essentially I am looking add a variable width `border` or `stroke` to a triangle, but my current attempts, which involve calculating the normal of each point and extending by the strokeWidth only work correctly on an equilateral triangle.

I'm an app developer and my math is poor at best.  My apologies if I have used any incorrect terminology throughout this question.

How can I calculate the `green` points `p0, p1, p2` and `i0, i1, i2` given any set of three initial triangle vectors and a variable `strokeWidth`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three triangles are *similar* (have the same angles) and can be obtain from one another by stretching away/towards the centre of the incircle. So once you compute the centre $c$ and radius $r$ of the incircle, the small triangle is obtained by stretching with as factor $1-\frac sr$ (i.e., $i_1=c+(1-\frac sr)(v_1-c)=(1-\frac sr)v_1+\frac src$ etc.) and the big triangle with the factor $1+\frac sr$.

To compute $c$, you may intersect the angular bisectors, i.e., intersect the line $v_1+t\cdot w_1$ with the line $v_2+t\cdot w_2$ where $w_1=\frac{v_2-v_1}{\|v_2-v_1\|}+\frac{v_3-v_1}{\|v_3-v_1\|}$ and  $w_2=\frac{v_1-v_2}{\|v_1-v_2\|}+\frac{v_3-v_2}{\|v_3-v_2\|}$.

Comment: Fantastic answer.  Very concise.  Thank you.